# Making the flex compiler warn about variables with the same name losing scope

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, warnings

Imagine that you have a class with a member variable

```
private var radius:Number;
```

And then inside a method you create a local variable with this same name

```
private function func():void{
    var radius:Number = 5;
}
```

Can I make the Flex compiler warn me about this situation? That I may actually want to use the member variable instead of this local variable I've just defined?

EDIT: I guess the flex compiler can't do that. Would be hard to make a as3 lint tool do that? I mean, I would code that.

Comment: I would be very surprised if this is possible, its a fundamental part of the language which often IS needed by programmers.

Comment: No the flex compiler has no flag for this kind of warning.

Comment: `this.radius` will explicitly reference the member variable, not the locally scoped variable.

Comment: As @32bitkid says, if you prefix your class variables with `this.` (which I find helps clarity as well), then you'll never run into this problem

Comment: the thing is, when I run into this problem I don't know that I'm doing that. And I don't think that using this all the time is really a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlexPMD already does that.

> A class property is hidden by this local variable

In FlashDevelop it's called "Analyze Project Source Code", the problem is, it have so many false alarms, or warning that are not really important that this problem may go unnoticed.

You can customize this ruleset by editing the file default-ruleset.xml (or you can create other one and set it on Program Settings -> Code Analyzer) located in Program Files/FlashDevelop/Tools/flexpmd.

Also, to make things easier you can create a shortcut in Tools -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> FlashToolsMenu.AnalyzeProject

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of compiler warnings in the Flex SDK's flex-config.xml file at this location:

```
frameworks/flex-config.xml
```

In Flex SDK 4.6 there is no warning listed in flex-config.xml that meet your requirements.

Have a look at [Viewing warnings and errors](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf67670-7fd5.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7eaf) in the Adobe Help docs for more info about Flex compiler warnings.